# How do you delete a file from a Windows installation if you see the error 'filename too long'

Tags: windows, file, powershell, names

I had a directory 'c:\windows.old\ leftover from upgrading Windows 8 to 8.1.  I wanted to delete the directory and could kill most of it using Windows Explorer shift+delete (delete no undelete).

However there were a few tricks left in there from good old MSFT themselves.  For some odd reason they decided that having really long names (RLNs) for the cache entries was a Good Idea.  Most Windows utilities (Del/Dir/PowerShell get-children) just die a stinking death when they see a file with a RLN.

So off on the hunt for something to put them out of their too-long misery.

Answer (score 1):

I found this PowerShell add-on module at http://poshcode.org/2488.  Joel's ps module adds several commands to ps, including get-longpath and remove-longpath.

1. Download the zip from his site and unzip it to C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\1.0\modules.  You should now have an Experimental.IO folder in the ps modules directory.
2. Crank up PowerShell ISE (windows key+x, select Windows
   PowerShell ISE) or open the PowerShell command windows (Windows key+x,
   Windows PowerShell).
3. Navigate to the directory with the offending RLN files (e.g. 'c:\Windows.old\users{{username}}\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Windows Store\Cache\0'.  Your ps prompt should now be:

Now on to more productive work.
    PS C:\Windows.old\users{{username}}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Store\Cache\0>

4. Enter this command: Get-LongPath | Remove-LongPath

This will pipe the RLN filenames to Remove-LongPath.  PowerShell just returns to the command prompt, but you verify there are no long files by entering Get-Longpath (or its alias glp) and Dir to see there are no long any RLN files in the directory.

As a last note, if you want to save yourself about an hour, refer to this [SO post](https://superuser.com/questions/515784/deleting-windows-old-folder) to ask Windows to delete the Windows.old folder on your behalf from the Disk Cleanup utility.

Comment: The Disk Cleanup utility is by far the easiest way.  One other option that doesn't require additional tools - rename folders - you're deleting them so the name no longer matters.  Start from the root and use single letter names, repeating for sub-folders until deleting succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

1) Put Linux on a thumb drive. Ubuntu will be fine.

2) Boot to the thumb drive.

3) Delete the files in question from the UI or from the command line:

`rm /path/to/file/that/you're/deleting/42915u02u51...24521.doc`

Honestly deleting it wth a Linux thumb drive is far simpler and more reliable than hoping Windows utilities and workarounds won't muck it up.